# Как применить removeEventListener конкретному плагину MODX?

Tags: modx

в modx есть такой метод $modx->removeEventListener, который удаляет событие из карты событий, чтобы оно не вызывалось. но как я понял, оно удаляет его для всей системы. а как снять отслеживание события у конкретного плагина?

MODX Revolution 2.7.3-pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/63ae5d2ae18589838ffd01ba0405bf3662d9496e/core/model/modx/modx.class.php#L1985
документацию, к сожалению,не обновили, хотя был фикс..вторым параметром передается ID плагина

```
public function removeEventListener($event, $pluginId = 0)
```

Документацию обновлю.